# Youtube API v3 Java

Tags: java, youtube, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to test the YouTube API v3 Example from Google. I downloaded the testfiles from GitHub: https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java , then I filled in the `client_id` and `client_secret` in `client_secrets.json` (`src/main/recourses`), I also filled in the API key in the `youtube.properties` file (`src/main/recourses`).

I'm using Eclipse.

Then I tried to run the `UploadVideo.java` file, but I'm getting the following error:

```
IOException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
```

What is the problem? My client_id and client_secret are correct. I create these on the Developer Console from Google.

[image: The overview]

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For any kinda data, we as a programer can eithe do insert ,delete or update. Same with data at google's server. You may have not set to update that data. Just go to dev console & properly change the settings for YT data api.